# Passport local returns error 400 bad request with postman

Tags: passport.js, passport-local

Hi i am getting 400 Bad Request error every time i use passport local. Please tell me where i am doing something wrong.

I am trying to call my /login route using postman but every time i am getting error of 400 Bad Request

Below is my code:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
{
    email:'email',
    password:'password'
},
function(email, password, done){
    adminModel.getAdmin(email, function(err, admin){
        if(err){ return done(err);}
        if(!admin){
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid Username.'});
        }
        adminModel.comparePassword(password, admin.password, function(err, isMatch){
            if(err){return done(err);}
            if(isMatch){
                return done(null, admin);
            }else{
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid Password'});
            }
        })
    });
}
));

passport.serializeUser(function(admin, done){
    done(null, admin._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    adminModel.findById(id,function(err, admin){
        done(err, admin);
    });
});
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'),function(req, res){
res.send(req.body);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

From what you've given its impossible to say for sure, but I would say nine out of ten times `HTTP Bad Request` comes from [this row](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/3139186da310680ee38576118eb43094408ce38e/lib/strategy.js#L75) in `passport-local`, ie. the request does not contain credentials.

Apparently you have tried to tell that the fields containing the credentials are `email` and `password` when you've defined this:

```
{
    email:'email',
    password:'password'
}
```

These options are [not supported](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local#available-options) by the middleware. You should pass

```
{
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
}
```

instead.

Another common reason is to not have `body-parser` in use, or the request you're sending from Postman does not define correct headers to match the data.

Comment: I found this searching for my issue and I'll add a stipulation: the middleware does support it, but you need to pass the object which declares new keys to look for i.e. `{
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'passwd',
    session: false
  }`