# Login with Passport Local returns 400 error to POST request (using Axios, MERN and React Hooks)

Tags: api, authentication, axios, react-hooks, passport.js

I am using Passport Local for the auth to my app. It is the first project I have used React Hooks to complete. The auth strategy is one that I have used previously when using class components in React. So I am curious if there is a difference in approach that I need to take into account.

Currently when I submit the 'email' and 'password' data in the form on the 'Login' component, I receive a 400 error response to my POST request and the corresponding message of 'Wrong credentials' (this message is simply a response to the 400 JSON response):

```
xhr.js:177 POST http://localhost:5005/api/auth/login 400 (Bad Request)
```

But I am using the exact inputs copied from the database. I believe this means that the data I am sending to be matched to a record (in this case the email) is not being read properly.

To make sure there wasn't a problem with my app accessing the users in the database, I created a seperate API request that returns all of the users. This does work. So It would appear to me that there is some problem with the data that I am sending to the database to be verified.

Can you see where I am making a mistake here?

## client/src/components/Login.js

```
    import {React, useState} from 'react'
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
    import { allUsers, login } from '../services/auth'
    
    // console.log('login loading')
    
    function useInput(initialValue){
      const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
      
      function handleChange(event){
        setValue(event.target.value);
      }
    
      return [value,handleChange]
    }
    
    export default function Login(props) {
      const [email, setEmail] = useInput('');
      const [password, setPassword] = useInput('');
      const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
      const [user, setUser] = useState('')
    
      const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('email:', email, 'password:', password)
        // allUsers().then(data => {
        //   console.log(data)
        // })
        login(email, password).then(data => {
          if (data.message) {
            // console.log(data.message);
            setMessage(data.message);
          } else {
            setUser(data)
            console.log(user);
            props.history.push('/dashboard');
          }
        });
      };
    
      // console.log('login function loading')
      return (
        <div>
        <h1>Login.js</h1>
        <div class='loginForm'>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    
            <label>Email</label>
            <input 
              type='text'
              name='email'
              value={email}
              onChange={setEmail}
              id='email'
            />
    
            <label>Password</label>
            <input 
              type='password'
              name='password'
              value={password}
              onChange={setPassword}
              id='password'
            />
            
    {message && (
    <alert variant='danger'>{message}</alert>
    )}
    
    <button type='submit'>Login</button>
    </form>
        </div>
        <Link to="/auth/google">Login With Google</Link>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

## client/src/services/auth.js

```
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    const allUsers = () => {
      return axios
      .get('/api/auth/users')
      .then(response => {
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.response.data)
      })
    }
    
    const signup = (email, password, firstname, lastname) => {
      return axios
        .post('/api/auth/signup', { email, password, firstname, lastname})
        .then(response => {
          // console.log(response)
          return response.data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          // console.log(err)
          return err.response.data;
        });
    };
    
    const login = (email, password) => {
      return axios
        .post('/api/auth/login', { email, password })
        .then(response => {
          return response.data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          return err.response.data;
        });
    };
    
    const logout = () => {
      return axios
        .delete('/api/auth/logout')
        .then(response => {
          return response.data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          return err.response.data;
        });
    };
    
    export { signup, login, logout, allUsers };
```

## routes/auth-routes.js

```
    const express = require('express');
    const passport = require('passport');
    const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
    const User = require('../models/User.model');
    
    const router = express.Router();
    
    // Get all users
    router.get('/users', (req, res) => {
      User.find().then((users) => {
        console.log(users);
        res.status(200).json(users);
      });
    });
    
    // Signup route
    router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
      const {
        email, password, firstname, lastname,
      } = req.body;
    
      if (!password || password.length < 8) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ message: 'Your password must be 8 char. min.' });
      }
      if (!email) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ message: 'Your email cannot be empty' });
      }
    
      // check if email exists in database -> show message
      User.findOne({ email })
        .then((found) => {
          if (found) {
            return res
              .status(400)
              .json({ message: 'This email is already taken' });
          }
    
          // hash the password, create the user and send the user to the client
          const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();
          const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
    
          return User.create({
            email, password: hash, firstname, lastname,
          }).then(
            (dbUser) => {
              // login with passport:
              req.login(dbUser, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                  return res
                    .status(500)
                    .json({ message: 'Error while attempting to login' });
                }
                return res.status(200).json(dbUser);
              });
            },
          );
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          res.json(err);
        });
    });
    
    // Login route
    
    router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
      passport.authenticate('local', (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error while authenticating' });
        }
        if (!user) {
          return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Wrong credentials' });
        }
        req.login(user, (error) => {
          if (error) {
            return res
              .status(500)
              .json({ message: 'Error while attempting to login' });
          }
          return res.status(200).json(user);
        });
      })(req, res, next);
    });
    
    // Delete user route
    router.delete('/logout', (req, res) => {
      req.logout();
      res.json({ message: 'Successful logout' });
    });
    
    // returns the logged in user
    router.get('/loggedin', (req, res) => {
      res.json(req.user);
    });
    
    // when login is successful, retrieve user info
    router.get('/login/success', (req, res) => {
      if (req.user) {
        res.json({
          success: true,
          message: 'user has successfully authenticated',
          user: req.user,
          cookies: req.cookies,
        });
      }
    });
    
    // auth with google
    router.get(
      '/google',
      passport.authenticate('google', {
        scope: [
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
        ],
      }),
    );
    router.get(
      '/google/callback',
      passport.authenticate('google', {
        successRedirect: '/private-page',
        // here you would redirect to the login page using traditional login approach
        failureRedirect: '/login',
      }),
    );
    
    module.exports = router;
```

## app.js

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const cors = require('cors');

// ℹ️ Gets access to environment variables/settings
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv
require('dotenv/config');

// ℹ️ Connects to the database
require('./db');

// Handles http requests (express is node js framework)
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/express

const express = require('express');

const app = express();

// ℹ️ This function is getting exported from the config folder. It runs most middlewares
require('./config')(app);

app.use(
  cors({
    // this could be multiple domains/origins, but we will allow just our React app
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
  }),
);

// session configuration

const session = require('express-session');

// session store using mongo
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

const mongoose = require('./db/index');

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    cookie: { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 },
    saveUninitialized: false,
    // Forces the session to be saved back to the session store,
    // even if the session was never modified during the request.
    resave: true,
    store: new MongoStore({
      mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
      url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017',
    }),
  }),
);
// end of session configuration

// passport configuration

const User = require('./models/User.model');

// we serialize only the `_id` field of the user to keep the information stored minimum
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
  done(null, user._id);
});

// when we need the information for the user, the deserializeUser function is called with
// the id that we previously serialized to fetch the user from the database
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id)
    .then((dbUser) => {
      done(null, dbUser);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      done(err);
    });
});

passport.use(
  // new GoogleStrategy(
  //   {
  //     clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENTID,
  //     clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENTSECRET,
  //     callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
  //   },
  //   (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  //     // to see the structure of the data in received response:
  //     console.log('Google account details:', profile);

  //     User.findOne({ googleID: profile.id })
  //       .then((user) => {
  //         if (user) {
  //           done(null, user);
  //           return;
  //         }

  //         User.create({ googleID: profile.id })
  //           .then((newUser) => {
  //             done(null, newUser);
  //           })
  //           .catch((err) => done(err)); // closes User.create()
  //       })
  //       .catch((err) => done(err)); // closes User.findOne()
  //   },
  // ),
  new LocalStrategy((email, password, done) => {
    // login
    User.findOne({ email: email })
      .then((userFromDB) => {
        if (userFromDB === null) {
          // there is no user with this email
          done(null, false, { message: 'This email does not exist in the database' });
        } else if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, userFromDB.password)) {
          // the password is not matching
          done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong password' });
        } else {
          // the userFromDB should now be logged in
          done(null, userFromDB);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }),

);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// end of passport

//  Start handling routes here
// Contrary to the views version, all routes are controled from the routes/index.js
const index = require('./routes');

app.use('/api', index);

const auth = require('./routes/auth-routes');

app.use('/api/auth', auth);

// Allows access to the API from different domains/origins BEFORE session
app.use(
  cors({
    // this could be multiple domains/origins, but we will allow just our React app
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
  }),
);

//  Start handling routes here
// Contrary to the views version, all routes are controled from the routes/index.js

// This could be a conflict with line 104, so I commented it out. We can reinstate
// const allRoutes = require('./routes');
// app.use('/api', allRoutes);

const admin = require('./routes/admin');

app.use('/api', admin);

// ❗ To handle errors. Routes that don't exist or errors that you handle in specific routes
require('./error-handling')(app);

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this problem after reviewing the Passport docs section where it discusses parameters being fed into the Local strategy:

http://www.passportjs.org/docs/username-password/

I also should have read vesse's solution to this problem because it also provided the same solution:

[Passport local returns error 400 bad request with postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42392630/passport-local-returns-error-400-bad-request-with-postman)

Essentially, as the Passport docs say:

> By default, LocalStrategy expects to find credentials in parameters
> named username and password. If your site prefers to name these fields
> differently, options are available to change the defaults.

The problem was that I had changed the parameters being fed into the new LocalStrategy to ‘email’ and ‘password’ where Passport only accepts ‘username’ and ‘password’. You can use the email as one of the arguments but it has to be defined as a username.

I added the following as the first parameter of the new LocalStrategy:

```
    {
          usernameField: 'email',
          passwordField: 'password',
        }
```

The full corrected code in my app.js:

```
new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: 'email',
      passwordField: 'password',
    },
    (email, password, done) => {
    // login
      User.findOne({ email })
        .then((userFromDB) => {
          if (userFromDB === null) {
          // there is no user with this email
            done(null, false, { message: 'This email does not exist in the database' });
          } else if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, userFromDB.password)) {
          // the password is not matching
            done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong password' });
          } else {
          // the userFromDB should now be logged in
            done(null, userFromDB);
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },
  ),

);
```